# How to upweight an arbitray feature in GBM?

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, feature-engineering, boosting

Are there any ways to upweight any particular feature for GBM (tree boosting)?

The motivation is:

Assuming one would like to put a few dummy indicators, e.g., X_A, X_B, X_C, ..., into GBM, for the original feature X that is categorical. The data is pretty thin for X == 'A'.

Normally GBM would treat each feature equally at each tree split, and as a result it is very likely that GBM would not split using X_A at all if on training sample the residual for X == 'A' is not significant enough.

However, if one already knows the residual of X == 'A' observed on the training sample is actually real based on some other knowledge (business, prior, etc.), is there any way to force GBM to upweight this particular feature X_A when splitting so that the output model can actually fit well to the observed residual?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you know much about offsets, but it sounds like you could tell the GBM to fit the effect you're certain of as an offset.

y~ x1 + x2 + offset(some function of X_A)